# SSIS : how to run stored procedure in Data Flow Task

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, ssis, etl

I have a Data Flow Task that does this:

1. From OLE DB Source, run a SQL Command to select some data
2. Lookup to a different SQL DB Source, check if the data already exists or not
3. Based on Lookup Match Output vs. Lookup No Match Output, run a stored procedure with different input parameters. The input parameters will be based on the 'Available Lookup Columns' results from #2

The question is how do I run and pass certain input parameters into my stored procedure?

[image]

Comment: You definitely want to consider moving the proc call to outside of the data flow task. Using `OLE DB Command` in your data flow like this will cause the proc to get called for each row that hits your `Lookup Match Output` path. This will be a major bottleneck in your data flow if you have more than a few records.
A better design would be to store your `Lookup Match Output` in a separate staging table, and then call your stored proc from an Execute SQL Task outside of the data flow. Then you can have the proc work with the data in your staging table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To execute a stored procedure with parameters in OLEDB Command, all you need write the SQL Command and use `?` to specify a parameters.

**Example:**

Consider the following stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.SpInputOutput

    @input as int,

    @output as datetime output

AS

BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;


    set @output=DATEADD(Day,@input,getdate())

END
```

You should write the following command:

```
exec SpInputOutput ? , ? output
```

And in the Columns Mapping dialog, Map the input columns to the parameters specified.

---

For more details, check the following links:

- [Output Parameter of Stored Procedure In OLE DB Command - SSIS](http://www.rad.pasfu.com/index.php?/archives/24-Output-Parameter-of-Stored-Procedure-In-OLE-DB-Command-SSIS.html)
- [SSIS OLEDB COMMAND AND PROCEDURE OUTPUT PARAMS](https://www.josefrichberg.com/journal/2011/6/30/ssis-oledb-command-and-procedure-output-params.html)

Comment: Thank you I think this might be working. For some reason there's nothing shown under the 'Available Destination Columns' because of an error with a completely unrelated other stored proc... will be asking around. But otherwise I think this is the correct solution.

Comment: @ichachan happy to help, if the solution solves the issue you have to accept it

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with only one SQL Server as a data source than it is more convenient and faster to write an SP with all the logic in it. Then you wouldn't have to transfer the data outside of SQL Server and have an extra moving part