# Getting a rowset from a Dataflow task (DTS) via stored procedure cursor/loop

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am a bit new to DTS/DTSX but for what I've learned I can't find the exact solution to what I need out of it for this problem. This answer is close but not quite:

[SSIS : how to run stored procedure in Data Flow Task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54428891/ssis-how-to-run-stored-procedure-in-data-flow-task)

What's needed:
Destination File task to write a text file every time the stored proc loops (cursor) and outputs new rowset to a staging table. Last rowset deleted for new incoming rowset. This whole operation is to split a huge file into multiple managable files. The rowset output can be altered by a counter, works nice for that already.

So far:
I have stored proc working fine in Execute SQL task, it loops and loads desired rowset. The problem is that I can't get the Data Flow + Destination File task chain to write out the file on every proc cursor loop, it will only write out the very last rowset out of the proc. I thought putting a For-Each task wrapper around the Data Flow task would work, but it's redundant, the For-Each still waits, apparently, for the stored proc to completely finish in the Execute SQL task, then writes out the final rowset only.

I essentially have to trigger the Data Flow/File Destination task on every cursor loop, or otherwise signal the Data Flow/File Destination task to "see" when a new rowset is now present in the staging table, the DF/FD task having cleaned up (deleted) its previous rowset after file writeout.

Everything works as intended but for this loop-rowset-writeout bit. Any ideas appreciated, thanks.

[current DTS package layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZ1gV.png)

Comment: The proc is not in the foreach loop so it will only execute once (even if there is a cursor in that).  It seems what you are looking for is counter to loop over in the FE loop and then call the proc iteratively from there, using a counter parameter to get subsequent rowsets

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for the quick reply. You're right, and I thought of trying to call the proc in the For/Each task, but because of a  lot of complicated logic/requirements for composing  and controlling the output rowsets, the cursor loops have to stay in the proc, it's the best place for it to be instead of spread throughout the DTS tasks. I did wonder though if the procedure logic couldn't be directly slapped into the For/Each task, i.e. fire the cursor within the For/Each somehow (actually there are two cursors, inner and outer...), with the inputs to these in the Execute SQL task. Dunno.

Comment: Clarification - the For/Each isn't even necessary except (maybe?) to fire the Data Flow/File Destination task for a new file for each rowset out of the cursor/s. However I can get the DF/FD to do that I don't care.

Comment: Could you describe what the proc returns? Is it the whole dataset that needs to be broken into files, is it a lot of datasets, something else?

Comment: it's just firing the same (final) query in the inner cursor...inserting that rowset to a staging table, and then hopefully out to a flat file. Over and over till the whole big daily rowset is punched in/out of the staging table. The outer cursor pulls the high-level key rows (customer level), inner cursor pulls all the many invoices for the outer row customer.

Comment: If the proc is loading a bunch of staging tables, then you need the foreach loop to iterate over each table, i.e. get the list of tables into a object variable, then pass each table name to another variable which will become the oledb source with each loop.  Am I understanding the design correctly?